# ¿Cómo numerar filas de un data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

¿cómo puedo llenar una columna con 1 y 2 de un data.frame en r? por ejemplo de las filas 1:2 con 1 y 3:4 con el 2

data

```
    Especie    Longitude  Latitude bins2
1  Xenoomys    -99.48703  19.91978  NA
2  Nelsonia    -102.34437 19.76218  NA
3  Neotoma     -103.65200 19.67459  NA
4  Hodomys     -103.67300 19.66625  NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Si tan sólo quieres añadir una columna con 1 y 2 sin ningún condicionante puedes usar directamente la función *rep(cantidad,nº de veces)* y luego añadir la columna al data frame con *cbind*. Sería así:

```
> dat

   especie  Longitude Latitude
1 Xenoomys  -99.48703 19.91978
2 Nelsonia -102.34437 19.76218
3  Neotoma   -103.652 19.67459
4  Hodomys   -103.673 19.66625

> bins2<-c(rep(1,2),rep(2,2)) # Aquí creas el vector, en el que se repiten dos veces el uno
                              # y dos veces el dos
> bins2
[1] 1 1 2 2

> (dat<-cbind(dat,bins2))

   especie  Longitude Latitude bins2
1 Xenoomys  -99.48703 19.91978     1
2 Nelsonia -102.34437 19.76218     1
3  Neotoma   -103.652 19.67459     2
4  Hodomys   -103.673 19.66625     2
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Ahinoa. ¿Pero para un data.frame con un número de filas mayor? digamos de 150 rows, de 1 al 70 el 1 y el resto con el 2

Comment: para un número mayor de filas solo tienes que corregir los datos del rep, es decir, si como dices tienes una data frame de 150 filas, y quieres que 70 sean una, en vez de poner `bins2<-c(rep(1,2),rep(2,2))` pon `bins2<-c(rep(1,70),rep(2,80))` donde el 70 y el 80 es el número de veces que quieres repetir el 1 y el 2 respectivamente.

Comment: Gracias nuevamente, me salvaste.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes resolverlo de la siguiente forma:

```
values <- c(1,1,2,2)
df[seq(values),c("$bins2")] <- values
```

- En primer lugar creamos un vector con los valores que vamos a completar en el orden en que lo vamos a hacer. Eventualmente puedes usar la función `rep` como ya te sugirió Ahinoa para generar los valores.
- Luego simplemente actualizamos solo las filas que se corresponde con los valores, usando `seq(values)`, lo cual nos dará un vector de `1` a la cantidad de valores, eventualmente, esto nos permite solo actualizar una parte del `data.frame`, por ejemplo los primeros `n` valores.

Esta solución cubre el caso en que la cantidad de valores en `values` sea inferior a la cantidad de filas del `data.frame`, pero no cubre el caso en que la cantidad sea mayor. Una forma bien segura que no te va a dar error en ningún caso sería normalizar los valores a reemplazar con el tamaño del `data.frame`, así:

```
# Actualizamos solo 3 valores
values <- c(1,1,2)[1:nrow(df)]

# Pero también funcionaría hacer esto
# values <- c(1,1,2,2,3)[1:nrow(df)] 

df[seq(values), c("bins2")] <- values
df

   Especie  Longitude Latitude bins2
1 Xenoomys  -99.48703 19.91978     1
2 Nelsonia -102.34437 19.76218     1
3  Neotoma -103.65200 19.67459     2
4  Hodomys -103.67300 19.66625    NA
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda Patricio Moracho. ¿Pero para un data.frame con un número de filas mayor? digamos de 150 rows, de 1 al 70 el 1 y el resto con el 2

Comment: @Engel, en ese caso el vector `values` lo podrías armar así: `c(rep(1, 70),rep(1, nrow(df)-70)`

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda